# how to wire ceiling fan with pull chain and light with 3-way switches

Tags: electrical

I have installed other ceiling fans with one switch for light and pull chain for fan. But now I'm installing one with 2 3-way switches (one on either end of room) for the light and the pull chain for the fan. Newly remodeled, contractors cut hole for fan and ran wire to hole. Wire is Romex: black (always hot), red (hot or dead, switched [one 3-way switch, other one not installed yet]), white (neutral), bare (ground). First I'll need a brace and box, can someone please help me with the wiring? Thanks, Pops

Comment: Those darn 3 way switches. They have one (hot input) and one hot output. When switched they just pass the hot to each other. The neural (white) just bypasses all that. The red would go to the fan/lamp and it is switchable form either of the two 3 way switches.

Comment: How is the layout of the wiring?  Is it supply->switch->other switch -> fan, that'd be a problem.  If one switch is a spur all its own, that's workable.

Comment: with the 3 ways switches you will always just switch the light, and fan with pull chain. But when the light is off there will be no Fan.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.